# Is there a replacement for GMongo in the Grails Gorm-MongoDB Plugin?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb, gmongo

I am dealing with an extremely large code base that heavily uses the GMongo library to simplify access to the mongo database. As I understand, beginning with GORM for MongoDB 5.0, gmongo was removed.

I now have a need to upgrade my mongo java driver to 3.4.2. This will require me to upgrade the GORM for MongoDB to 5.0. I am quickly realizing that if there is no replacement for GMongo, I am looking at an extremely huge effort to remove gmongo usage from our entire codebase (consisting of 10 applications and over 20 plugins). Does anyone know how I can get around this without completely removing the usage of GMongo syntax in my codebase?

Comment: I hate to resurrect what looks like a dead question but did you ever find an answer/solution to this?

I'm currently faced with a similar problem upgrading a Grails2/Mongo3 app to Grails 5 and adding PowerBI support, which requires MongoDB v4 at a minimum.

This will break the application's Mongo queries as they are all written in GMongo format. There are a hell of a lot of them as well.